# trouble with paths at local typo3 installation

Tags: php, apache, typo3

I have a problem after installing bs_dist extension to typo3 at xampp. i set up a blank typo3 installation, afterwards installed bs_dist extension. this worked, i can call the default page which is generated by that extension. 
the problem is that images are not shown

```
default-page url:
http://localhost/typo3/typo3/index.php?id=1

image path:
<img src="/fileadmin/files/welcome.gif" ...>
= http://localhost/fileadmin/files/welcome.gif     
but there should be written:
http://localhost/typo3/typo3/fileadmin/files/welcome.gif
this would work.
```

so how to change the path of the image?

my folder structure:

```
-- htdocs
   -- another_custom_project
   -- typo3
      -- typo3
         -- fileadmin
         -- typo3
         -- ...
```

Comment: You should change add a domain that points to the htdocs/typo3/typo3 folder. You need a VirtualHost in you Apache.

Comment: thanks for the keywords

Answer (score 1):

edit: here is my solution on windows 7 with xampp

1) create a subdomain of localhost at windows:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

add following, if first of these two lines is commented out, uncomment it

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.0.1    yourVirtualServersName.localhost
```

2) tell apache which path should be used for that subdomain by adding the following to

```
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/path/to/your/folder"
    ServerName yourVirtualServersName.localhost
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerAlias www.yourVirtualServersName.localhost
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/path/to/your/folder">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```